# Android WebView - full screen image not displaying in landscape mode

Tags: android, html, css, android-webview

I have a very simple webpage that contains a single image. The image should take up the whole page. In portrait orientation, it should fill the width (width: 100%; height: auto;), and in landscape orientation, it should fill the height (height: 100%; width: auto;).

I have verified that the page works correctly on Chrome Mobile. It just doesn't work in the WebView. Here's the HTML:

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
<title></title>
</head>

<body style="background-color: black; margin: 0px; padding: 0px;">
    <img id="imgWindow" alt="Full Screen Image" src="oxygenbooklet2014cover.jpg"
        style="border: 0px; padding: 0px; margin: 0px; vertical-align: top;">
</body>

<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function() {
        $(window).bind("orientationchange", onOrientationChange);
        setOrientationLayout();
    });

    function onOrientationChange(event) {
        setOrientationLayout();
    }

    // Fill image by width in portrait, and fill image by height in landscape
    function setOrientationLayout() {
        if (window.orientation == 0 || window.orientation == 180) {
            // Portrait
            $("#imgWindow").css("width", "100%");
            $("#imgWindow").css("height", "auto");
        } else if (window.orientation == 90 || window.orientation == -90) {
            // Landscape
            $("#imgWindow").css("width", "auto");
            $("#imgWindow").css("height", "100%");
        }

        alert(window.orientation);
    }
</script>

</html>
```

I'm running this within a WebView. The page is showing correctly in the portrait orientation, but for some reason the web page is not even visible in landscape.

Here's the Java code for the WebView's layout in the Fragment:

```
LinearLayout layout = new LinearLayout(getActivity());
layout.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
layout.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
layout.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
layout.addView(myWebView);
```

The Fragment is within an Activity, which has a ViewPager, with the following layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" 
    android:background="#98AFC7"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.ihtp.bsc">

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/pager"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#E5E4E2"
        />
    <com.viewpagerindicator.CirclePageIndicator
        android:id="@+id/indicator"
        android:padding="10dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:background="#2E2E2E"
        />
</LinearLayout>
```

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Which version of the Android platform are you testing this on?

Comment: I'm in Android API 18.

Comment: How does your Java handle the Android configuration change that comes with rotating the device? By default, Android will kill and restart your Activity. Could that be the problem? Please see http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html for more information.

Comment: Yes, it's the default behaviour, i.e. the Activity is restarted. But why would this be the problem? It should just recreate the layout and reload the webpage with the new orientation?

Comment: Right, I was just checking that that's how your app was working :)

Comment: Just to be really clear - you are sure that after the layout is recreated your code to load the URL is being run again?

Comment: Yes, it is definitely being run again. I verified this with a debugger.

Comment: If you start the app up in landscape mode and then rotate to portrait how does it behave?

Comment: Same thing - when starting in landscape, the web page doesn't appear, and rotating back to portrait the page appears with the image just fine.

Comment: Does your `alert(window.orientation);` fire with the expected value when in landscape?

Comment: Yes, the values are correct.

Comment: ok, next thing to try ... rather than using width:auto and height:100% in landscape, if you hardcode something like 100px for both, do you at least see the image show up?

Comment: Yes, the image comes up in both orientations when a hard-coded value is entered in place of 100%.

Comment: OK, cool. Can you try switching the widhth/height ordering so height:100% comes before width:auto in landscape?

Comment: Tried that too...same result.

Comment: Hmm, you have a 0 height for your viewpager... A 100% height of 0 is 0, right?

Comment: I don't think so, the ViewPager itself comes up fine. But anyway, I set the ViewPager's height to 100dip. Now, the ViewPager itself is always fixed at 100px. Same result - the web page shows in the in portrait mode, but it's blank in landscape.